# How to upload a file to GCS only if it is of a specific version in Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I have a case of using GCS to store files to upload files. I would like to avoid race conditions by using generations and preconditions (`x-goog-if-generation-match`).

There is an explanation how to do that in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions).

However, I am using Java API and the docs only shows json/xml api.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found is doing something like this:

```java
    Blob object =
        storage.get(
            bucketName,
            filePath,
            Storage.BlobGetOption.fields(BlobField.GENERATION));
    long generation = object.getGeneration();

    // now do some other stuff that might cause race conditions...

    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName, generation);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
    List<Storage.BlobWriteOption> blobWriteOptions = new ArrayList<>();
    blobWriteOptions.add(BlobWriteOption.generationMatch());
    
    // in case generation don't match this will throw "StorageException: 412 Precondition Failed"
    try (WriteChannel writer =
        storage.writer(blobInfo, blobWriteOptions.toArray(new BlobWriteOption[0]))) {
            writer.write(); // etc'
      }
    }
```